# How to get child records from parent in custom metadata type

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, custom-metadata

I have 4 custom meta datatypes

1. Dynamic Datatable
2. Dynamic Datatable Columns
3. Dynamic Datatable Cell Attributes
4. Dynamic Datatable Type Attributes

The structure of this looks like this:
[image]

Here Data Table is super parent, Data table Columns is parent, Datatable Cell Attributes and Datatable Type Attributes are children of Datatable Columns

I'm trying to get all the child records from the super parent (Datatable), is this possible without soql?

Comment: You can write your own utility by using getAll() method of custom metadata type. Also, if you're avoid SOQL bcz of governor limit, please be informed that mdt soql won't be considered for governor limit calculations.